# Ajax posting sometimes passing through url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In the analytics I see
/?username=abc123&password=abc123

I can login but those who I see are getting there can they? 
Heres my ajax call:

```
$('#login').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api.php',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            action: 1
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#login-loading').show();
            $('#loginBtn').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $(".login-bg").css('padding-top', 100);
            $(".login-bg").css('background', 'url(/img/ghost1.gif) 50% -30px');
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#login-loading').hide();
            $('#loginBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
            $(".login-bg").css('padding-top', 10);
            $(".login-bg").css('background', '#ffffff');
        },
        success: function(data){          
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(data[0]==1) {
                $(".login-status").append('<div class="alert alert-success">Logging you in...</div>');
                location.reload();
            } else {
                $(".login-status").append('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>'+data[1]+'</div>')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How come it's doing that and is it preventing them to login?

Comment: `event` doesn't exist

Comment: Please explain? Do I need to put function(event) { } ?

Comment: @user3211562: Yes. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/, http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/. Please read the documentation before you use a method.

Comment: preventDefault works on anchor tag, if you are not using anchor tag then you can that part.

Answer (score 0):

stringify json before posting.

and add `contentType: 'application/json'`